# Why does printing the address of a variable using printf changes the address

Tags: c, arrays

Code 1

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n[] = {0};
    int i = 1;
    n[0] = i; //making sure the variable is used
    n[-1] = 20; //i's offset when &i is printed
    printf("%d\n", &i);
    printf("%d\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

Output1

```
2686744
20
```

Code 2

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n[] = {0};
    int i = 1;
    n[0] = i; //making sure the variable is used
    n[1] = 20; //i's offset when &i isn't printed
    printf("%d\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

Output2

```
20
```

If I use 1 as offset when printing and -1 when not, no overwriting occurs. I've tried printing other addresses and values but nothing more happens.

I believe it doesn't concern the use or not of the i variable since I tried to add a bit of code for the compiler to deem it used.

Also tried compiling explicitly without optimizations (-O0) without a change with the results.

Comment: Why does “Output1” show only one number? Shouldn't it print the address of `i` before it prints 20? (Notwithstanding the undefined behavior...)

Comment: Sorry i mixed both outputs, fixed now

Comment: I don't understand what change you are referring to and how it might be related to printf.

Comment: @JeffRSon the line "printf("%d\n", &i);" is the only difference between the two programs, that and the out of bounds offset on the line prior to that. on the first one i access the memory preceding n and on the second one the memory following n.

Comment: Well, what happens if the only change would be +1/-1? And what's the address of n? I don't see the point so far. This is of course related when and how the compiler puts the variables on the stack. Especially in such "undefined" situation. Maybe you should have a look at the assembly code (you could get it from gcc).

Comment: Apart from the gross UB as described by Sourav, '%d' is the wrong specifier for printing pointer values.

Comment: @MartinJames you confused me for a second there. I thought I missed that in my answer. :)

Comment: @JeffRSon As documented in my question, just changing the offset doesn't overwrite the variable since the memory accessed isn't i's one (and should give a crash on some systems). And, right, I might as well take a look at the asm. :)

Comment: For documentation's sake here's the asm dump of both functions, the one on the right being the one printing the address http://imgur.com/pfvhSGt the main thing I can see is the addresses being inverted, that would explain the behaviour. No idea what causes that to happen though.

Comment: @SouravGhosh no - I missed it in your answer:)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With a definition like `int n[] = {0};`, you have got only one element in the array, i.e., `n[0]` is the only valid access.

In your first code,

```
 n[-1] = 20;
```

is invalid memory access.

In your second code,

```
n[1] = 20;
```

is too accessing out of bound memory. Both the cases invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Also, to print an address, you need to use `%p` format specifier and cast the argument to `(void *)`.

Comment: I would very much appreciate getting to know the reason behind the downvote. Thanks. :)

Comment: no downvote from me, but I was mostly asking if there was a reason behind the consistent sudden change of address? On the other hand I understand perfectly the fact that this is invalid memory access.

Comment: @Angrevol In case your code invokes UB, there is nothing that can guarantee it is doing anything sane. :)

Comment: Haha fair enough. I suppose i was expecting a more concrete answer. Thanks.

Comment: @MartinJames :) Right, except one thing, DVs. I don't see why I keep getting DVs on this answer. Did I miss something very obvious?

Answer (score 0):

There are some things to be careful ...
In the first code, print it "i" and its direction, but there is a small error
  n [-1] = 20

These lines of code are not important for printing, it goes out of the array ..

The second code ...

also it has a small error n [1] = 20;

Comment: This Answer it may not be the perfect Answer, but I do not understand, what exactly does this Answer to be wrong to get down voted. Just because of "smaller error"?